# While opening MuleSoft's Anypoint Studio I am getting an error

Tags: anypoint-studio

While opening MuleSoft Anypoint Studio I am getting below error.

Java Runtime env (JRE) Or Java development kit(JDK) must be available in order to run Anypoint studio.
No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
plugins/org.mule.tooling.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.1.1/bin/javaw.exe

Anypoint studio - 7.11.0 version
JDK -  1.7 version

I have kept JAVA_HOME and path as  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin"

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint Studio 7.11 can only be started with Java/OpenJDK 11. For that reason it is distributed with with its own JVM. For some reason it seems to be missing in your installation. Maybe an antivirus removed it. Maybe you need to re download it. In any case you should be downloading Studio 7.11.1 instead.

You have separately installed a very very old Java 1.7.0 which is not compatible with Studio 7 at all. Also that Java 1.7.0 is probably a high security for you, since it is the last public release of Java 7 and has not been patched for about 6 years, but I will leave that to you to consider. It is not only not compatible with Studio but it is also not compatible with any current version of Mule.

Answer (score 0):

For Anypoint Studio series 7, you dont need any JAVA JDK as it is bundled with openJDK. But if any chnace its giving you an error of JDK, then try to download a fresh zip file of anypoint Studio form Mulesoft downnload webiste

https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/dl/studio

Or try to download the Java/OpenJDK 11 from this link

https://adoptopenjdk.net/ and set environment variables with this new JDK